# Deserialize JSON into multiple inherited classes

Tags: c#, json, reflection, azure-cosmosdb

When I serialize my JSON object out of DocumentDB, my `Control` is not deserializing into the `OptionsControl` with the `Options` property.

I have the following class, `Control`:

```
public class Control : IControl
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Enums.ControlType Type { get; set; }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public string ControlCssClass { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I also have `OptionsControl`, which inherits from `Control`:

```
public class OptionsControl : Control
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> Options;
}
```

I also have a `ClickableControl`:

```
public class ClickableControl : Control
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string UrlTarget { get; set; }
}
```

I used the Document Explorer in Azure to put this JSON in `document` in a DocumentDB `collection`:

```
Rows:
[
    {
        Controls:
        [
            {
              "PropertyName": "Relationship",
              "ControlCssClass": "",
              "Description": "",
              "Type": 3,
              "Options": [
                  {
                    "Key": "Spouse",
                    "Value": "Spouse"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "Child",
                    "Value": "Child"
                  },
                  {
                    "Key": "Step-child",
                    "Value": "Step-child"
                  }
              ],
           }
        ]
    }
]
```

When I pull the data out of DocumentDB, I attempt to serialize it into my `Row` class:

```
public class Row
{
    public IList<Control> Controls { get; set; }
}
```

I need to be able to put any type of "Control" in my Control list in DocDB and have C# deserialize that list back into the proper `Control` class (be that the base `Control` class, or one of the derivatives like `OptionsControl` or `ClickableControl`).

The problem is since I'm deserializing into `Control`, I get all of the properties on the Control except for `Options`. Or if I try to deserialize one that has `Url` and `UrlTarget`, I just get the base Control properties and not the URL properties. I thought C# would handle turning the deserialized object into an OptionsControl or a ClickableControl, but I guess that is incorrect? What do I need to do so that the JSON object from DocumentDB serializes properly and turns into an `OptionsControl` (has the Options property) instead of just the base Control?

Comment: Then deserialize an `OptionsControl`?

Comment: I need to deserialize into multiple Control class derivatives.

Comment: I've handled a similar issue in the past by including the implementation type when saving the data. This would allow dynamic creation of implementations of the `Control` type without specifying the it compile time.

Comment: @DannyBogers I can definitely add the control type. That's all I have to do and C# will handle the rest? Sounds too simple! Haha! But I will start there.

Comment: @Targaryen It's almost as simple as that, you can instantiate a `Type` from a full name, and if your serialization API supports it, tell it to deserialize your control of that specific type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try serializing your objects yourself with Json.NET and then posting the serialized content into DocumentDb. Then, when you need the data, read it back as a json string and use Json.NET again to deserialize.
Json.NET can handle inheritance, so you just have to configure it to be aware of your type hierarchy. Use the TypeNameHandling setting:

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};
```

Comment: Oh wow OK. So I need to use Json.NET to do the serialization first. That's very cool! I will try this out.

Comment: Your solution is genius. Thanks for the link to the TypeNameHandling documentation. Now my only problem is this... DocDB does the serialization/deserialization on its own using an older version of Json.NET. I need to figure out how to turn on the `TypeNameHandling.All` feature within the DocDB serialization settings somwhere...

Comment: Well, if all else fails, you can use the REST API for DocumentDb and post the serialized json string content yourself...

Comment: Or maybe you can try using the global configuration for Json.NET? Not sure, but might be worth a shot. Check this out:
http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DefaultSettings.htm

Comment: Sounds like a great idea! Checking it out!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks a ton! Obviously this is a legit question which you were able to answer. Other people surely have this problem with DocDB if they are abstracting any of their classes. I bet lots of people will end up coming here and using your answer. Not sure why the question was downvoted.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: A useful note: For the deserialization to work properly you would need to have `$type` metadata field added into the string as well. If not, the deserialization wouldn't work. Check this link for further details https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm